# Matlab awful matrix printing

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix 2x4, it looks like that

```
m_E =

   1.0e+30 *

   8.161150222102073                 Inf                 Inf   0.000000000000000
                 Inf                 Inf                 Inf   0.000000000000000
```

How I can display the matrix to make it looks without the first line with `1.0e+30 *`?

I want something like this

```
m_E =

   8.161150222102073 * 1.0e+30       Inf                 Inf   0.000000000000000
                 Inf                 Inf                 Inf   0.000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either

```
format shortg
```

or

```
format longg
```

.

You will get the *most locally compact* notation admissible. [`format` reference](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

Test:

```
  format longg
  m_E =
  8.16115022210207e+030    Inf          Inf             0
            ...

  format shortg
  m_E =
  8.1612e+030          Inf          Inf            0
            ...
```